# Jackson: deserialize complex object reference

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am calling a proprietary API that return a complex JSON:

```
{
    data: {
        id: 123,
        name: 'foo',
        createdBy: {
            id: 234,
            type: 'user'
        },
        currency: {
            id: 456,
            type: 'currency'
        }
    },
    links: {
        user: [
            {
                id: 234,
                fullName: 'Peter'
            }
        ],
        currency: [
            {
                id: 234,
                symbol: 'Euro'
            }
        ]
      }
 }
```

Instead of referencing the object using `@idRef` or something like that, they use an object with two properties: a type and a id.
Then I need to lookup for the corresponding object in the links structure.

Is it possible to deserialize this JSON using Jackson into:

```
public class Foo {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private User createdBy;
    private Currency currency;
}

public class User {
    private int id;
    private String fullName;
}

public class Currency {
    private int id;
    private String symbol;
}
```

I tried to find answers for "ObjectIdResolver" but I couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Why not do the mapping in your code instead?

Comment: That's what I acheive for now. But It became painfull when the data structure become more complex. I need to do `User createBy = MyDeserializerUtil.findUser(answer.getLinks(), theId)`, then `Currency currency = MyDeserializerUtil.findCurrency(answer.getLinks(), theId)` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `com.google.gson.Gson;` lib to parse your JSON string to a java object.
First, you need to design your java representation on JSON string.

```
class DataObject{
    public Data data;
    public Links links;
}

class Links{
    public List<User> user;
    public List<Currency> currency;
}

class Data{
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    public CommanObject createdBy;
    public CommanObject currency;
}

class CommanObject{
    public Long id;
    public String type;
}
class User{
    public Long id;
    public String fullName;
}

class Currency{
    public Long id;
    public String symbol;
}
```

To parse JSON String try below code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
DataObject dataObject = gson.fromJson(metaDataString, DataObject.class);
```

Second solution as you already using Jackson lib than try below one:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DataObject obj = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, DataObject.class);
```

Comment: He asked a solution for Jackson, not Google Gson

Comment: I acheive exactly the same in Jackson. If Gson can solve my problem, I'm ok to switch.